# Can I distinguish Integer and Double type in rapidjson

Tags: rapidjson

When I ask type of `rapidjson::Value` using `GetType()` method, it returns only belows Type:

```
//! Type of JSON value
enum Type {
    kNullType = 0,      //!< null
    kFalseType = 1,     //!< false
    kTrueType = 2,      //!< true
    kObjectType = 3,    //!< object
    kArrayType = 4,     //!< array
    kStringType = 5,    //!< string
    kNumberType = 6     //!< number
};
```

As you can see, there are no such `kIntType` nor `kDoubleType` (even `kUintType`, `kInt64Type`) Therefore, I can't get actual value of `rapidjson::Value`.

For example:

```
if (value.GetType() == rapidjson::kNumberType)
{
    double v = value.GetDouble()        // this?
    unsigned long v = value.GetUInt64() // or this??
    int v = value.GetInt()              // or this?
}
```

Is there anyway to distinguish actual numeric type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are:

1. `bool Value::IsInt() const`
2. `bool Value::IsUint() const`
3. `bool Value::IsInt64() const`
4. `bool Value::IsUint64() const`
5. `bool Value::IsDouble() const`

Note that, 1-4 are not exclusive to each other. For example, the value `123` will make 1-4 return `true` but 5 will return `false`. And calling `GetDouble()` is always OK when `IsNumber()` or 1-5 is `true`, though precision loss is possible when the value is actually a 64-bit (unsigned) integer.

http://miloyip.github.io/rapidjson/md_doc_tutorial.html#QueryNumber

Comment: Thank you for great JSON Parser, Milo ;)